# unable to remotly query rpm

Tags: ssh, rpm

I am querying rpm database using `--qf` flag

```
rpm -q --qf '<prm><N>%{N}</N></rpm>' --all
```

this work fine locally, now when I try to `ssh` it

```
 ssh -l root ${host} rpm -q --qf '<prm><N>%{N}</N></rpm>' --all
```

I get

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '<' 
bash: -c: line 0: `rpm -q --qf <prm><N>%{N}</N></rpm> --all'
```

Note that

- second line has a backquote and a forward quote,
- using double quote give same error,
- real use use `%{N}`, `%{V}`, `%{INSTALLTIME:date}` ...

I am missing something obvious, but what ?

Comment: duplicate explain **why** whereas @stephenkitt explain **how** to fix.

Comment: I am not saying Stephen answer is wrong (I upvoted already), but this is a question that comes around all the time and after reading the answer "why", you will be able to understand "how" to fix it (even though it is not explicitly written there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an extra level of quoting:

```
ssh -l root ${host} "rpm -q --qf '<prm><N>%{N}</N></rpm>' --all"
```

Without the extra double quotes, the command given to the remote shell is

```
rpm -q --qf <prm><N>%{N}</N></rpm> --all
```

and the shell interprets `<` etc.

In the error message, the backtick and single quote are actual quotes, used to quote the command. They’re not part of the command given to the shell.